# A word or phrase for something cruel whispered behind someone's back

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I need a word that means the above. I have a character who is a bit of an outcast and people whisper horrible things about her whenever she's around. Any ideas?

The sentence is:

> Hours afterwards, miles from school, she could still hear the *hateful remarks* whispered between friends when they thought she couldn’t hear.

Comment: Could you give a sample sentence, please? It helps to know if you want a noun, verb, adjective etc. I presume you want a noun?

Comment: Of course... 'Hours afterwards, miles from school, she could still hear the hateful remarks whispered between friends when they thought she couldn’t hear.' Something that might replace 'remarks'. Thank you!

Comment: The most obvious answer is:  a malicious rumour.  A rumour is a whispered story, and ‘malicious’ means ‘intending hurt or harm’.  It is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular vocabulary used  depends very much on the situation.

Discommend, discommendation: consider the usual uses of "commendation" in an academic, policing or military context, perhaps formally, perhaps with sardonic humour. The colloquial "Slagged (me) off" would be more casual.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/trash-talk

> abuse, scold,
>   disapprove (of), dislike,
>   censure, condemn, criticize, denounce, reprehend, reprobate,
>   asperse, defame, malign, rip, slander, slur, traduce, vilify,
>   discredit, disgrace

- quite a few usefull synonyms and synonymous phrases, many of which can take both noun and verbal forms. Again, the context and persons involved must determine which is used.

Answer (score 1):

[**Slander**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/slander).

From American Heritage (link above):

> 2. A false and malicious statement or report about someone.

Comment: Malicious, yes. However, the things that are whispered about my character aren't false. They're entirely true. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could desribe them as muttering "**barbed** comments".

> A barbed remark or joke seems polite or humorous, but contains a cleverly hidden criticism.